# Drawing on canvas with opacity (dots in line) javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drawing

I have that drawing logic:

```
Draw = function(canvas, ctx, mousePosition) {

    var grad = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, canvas[0].width, 0);
    grad.addColorStop(0, currentLineColor);
    grad.addColorStop(1, currentLineColor);

    ctx.lineWidth = currentLineWidth;
    ctx.strokeStyle = grad;
    ctx.lineCap = 'round';
    ctx.lineJoin = 'round';
    ctx.globalAlpha = 0.4;

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(lastMousePosition.x, lastMousePosition.y);
    ctx.lineTo(mousePosition.x, mousePosition.y);
    ctx.stroke();
};
```

When i set the globalAlpha to set opacity in this code a see dots in my drawn line. This logic is attached to mosemove event.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, that is to be expected as each line is overdrawn at the connection points, and their alpha data will add up.

I would suggest the following approach and attach a proof-of-concept demo at the end, feel free to adopt that code to your project:

1. Create two canvases, one main and one draft on top
2. Set the alpha directly on the top element using CSS (opacity) and always keep `globalAlpha=1`
3. For each stroke (pen down, pen up) draw on draft canvas (use lines between each point)
4. On pen up, set `globalAlpha` on main canvas equal the CSS opacity of top canvas
5. Draw top canvas to main canvas using `drawImage()`.
6. Clear top canvas, eat, sleep, repeat (from 3).

## Proof-of-concept

```js
var draft = document.getElementById("draft");
var main = document.getElementById("main");
var ctx = draft.getContext("2d");
var mctx = main.getContext("2d");
var isDown = false, prev, alpha = 0.4;

// setup pen
ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(0,200,127)";
ctx.lineWidth = 16;
ctx.lineCap = "round";                              // important to make lines cont.

// set up alpha
draft.style.opacity = alpha;                        // CSS alpha for draft
mctx.globalAlpha = alpha;                           // context alpha for main

draft.onmousedown = function(e){
  isDown = true; 
  prev = getXY(e);                                  // set prev. point as start
};

window.onmousemove = function(e){
  if (!isDown) return;
  var point = getXY(e);
  ctx.beginPath();                                  // new path
  ctx.moveTo(prev.x, prev.y);                       // start at prev. point
  ctx.lineTo(point.x, point.y);                     // line to new point
  ctx.stroke();                                     // stroke
  prev = point;                                     // update prev. point
};

window.onmouseup = function(){
  isDown = false;                                   // when up:
  mctx.drawImage(draft, 0, 0);                      // copy drawing to main
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, draft.width, draft.height);   // clear draft
};

function getXY(e) {
  var r = draft.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {x: e.clientX - r.left, y: e.clientY - r.top}
}
```

```css
#draft {cursor:crosshair}
.sandwich {position:relative}
.sandwich>canvas {position:absolute;left:0;top:0}
```

```html
<div class="sandwich">
  <canvas id="main" width=600 height=600></canvas>
  <canvas id="draft" width=600 height=600></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: This is fantastic and works perfectly. I have one question, is it possible to right click and save the image? Currently it returns an empty image, because I guess the empty canvas is returned rather than the main one?

Comment: @almostabeginner it's a good question, almost deserves a separate post :) but a quick workaround is to set draft canvas' [pointer-events](https://devdocs.io/css/pointer-events) to none, attach the canvas specific event handlers to the main one but keep using the draft context to draw.

Comment: Quite impressive, this seems like a really good solution. Thank you !